# After migration, CSS/JS file only for a few category aren't loaded properly

Tags: magento-2.1, migration

There.

I just checked my migration works well.
By the way, i can see a weird issue on our home page.

My devwebsite url is http://dev.kbethos.com/
And the url under this issue http://dev.kbethos.com/blanks-classics.html
Resources on other url except this seems to be loaded well without problem.

What is the issue of it?
I have tried migration work over and over again. It still happens

Comment: In that page no css & js calling check your xml files check your head tag in that page

Comment: Which xml file do you mean?

Comment: Open page check head tag